# Can't get workflow to show up on D7 Menus

Tags: 7, workflows

The workflow menu doesn't seem to show in the menu system in Drupal 7. The only place that I see "workflow" is in the configuration section, and it appears as a section called "workflow" and it only has Rules in it!

This is the exact same problem on the documentation (https://drupal.org/node/872876), however that did not help!

I've installed workflow UI and workflow API, Rules and Rules UI,  flushed all caches, uninstalled rules and workflow modules, reinstalled, tried various combinations of the modules, etc. Still no workflow option in the configuration menu.

I must be missing something stupid because lots of people are using workflow...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your account has "Administer workflow" permission.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have the following permissions set for allow: -Schedule workflow transitions; -Show workflow state change on node view; -Participate in workflows; -Administer workflow. Still no dice.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having this same problem. The issue is the implementation of `hook_permission()` in the 7.x-2.3 version.
You can update to a beta or you can edit that hook in the Workflow module.

Currently, workflow's menu access looks for "administer workflow" when the permission is "administer workflows"; the access is always denied because nobody has the "administer workflow" permission, which cannot be assigned from the UI since no module defines it.